# Golang открыть файл начинающийся с определенного символа

Tags: golang

Есть вот такая функция.

```
func Xmlparser(files []*multipart.FileHeader) (err error) {
    for _, file := range files {
        err, filename := utils.Unzip(patch_load.Upload_dir.Patch + file.Filename, patch_load.Upload_dir.Patch)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("err, filename := utils.Unzip(patch_load.Upload_dir.Patch + file.Filename, patch_load.Upload_dir.Patch):", err)
            return err
        }
}
```

После вызова utils.Unzip в filename получаем два имени файла.

Например filename[0] -> H_file213123.xml.
 filename[1] -> L_file234234.xml.

Нужно открыть файл который начинается с буквы L (порядок в массиве может быть разный, нулевым элементом может оказать и L файл)

Comment: И с чем у вас возникают сложности? Вы не можете пройтись по массиву? Не говоря уже о том, что вы не говорите, что делать если таких файлов несколько, или нету вообще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я бы использовал  пакет  "regexp" и
switch {
}
но соглашусь с комментатором, что  для решения  слишком мало данных. Если файлов  и вправду 2, то это решение вполне подойдёт.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "regexp"
)

var fileReg1 = regexp.MustCompile(`^H_file\d+.xml`)
var fileReg2 = regexp.MustCompile(`^L_file\d+.xml`)

var file1 string = "H_file213123.xml."
var file2 string = "L_file234234.xml."

func main() {
        files := []string{file1, file2}

        for _, file := range files {
                switch {
                case fileReg1.MatchString(file):
                        fmt.Println(file, "file A")
                case fileReg2.MatchString(file):
                        fmt.Println(file, "file B")
                default:
                        fmt.Println(file, "Not A  and  not B")
                }
        }
}
```